# How can I make summernote not execute script-tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, summernote

I have a form. My form use textarea(The textarea use summernote / https://github.com/summernote/summernote)

On the add data, I input the textarea like this :

```
<script>alert('x');</script>
```

It's success insert to table

But when I edit the data, there is display alert message like this :

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I think this question may need to be better described possibly with more provided code. I'm not quite sure what it's about at the moment.

Comment: @BarryMode, Look at this : https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/1462. My case like that

Comment: ok that makes sense. In general, the intended behavior of the editor is to render the code and that includes the script tag. I think the ideal solution is to have the maintainers of the project do it, but it looks like they haven't responded in over a year. Have you considered an alternative editor such as [tinymce](https://www.tinymce.com)?

Comment: @BarryMode, Okay thanks. Maybe I will try tinymce :)